# Dash Leaflet popup to show multiline with links

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dash-leaflet

I have make a simple map using dash-leaflet and I wanted to add a popup based on some data that I have.

This data contains names, prices and links which I would like to show in the popup.

I tried to do the following but it gave this result:

```
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
            # title = str(row['title'])
            # price = str("{:,}".format(row['price']))
            title = "hello" #example value
            price = "1" #example value
            link = "<a href='https://www.w3schools.com/'>Visit W3Schools.com!</a>"
            marker_text = title + "\n" + price + "\n" + "<b>" + link + "</b>"

        markers.append(
            dl.Marker(
                title=row['title'],
                position=(row['latitude'], row['longitude']),
                children=[
                    dl.Popup(marker_text),
                ],
            )
        )
    children = dl.MarkerClusterGroup(id="markers", children=markers)
```

[image]

I also tried to format the marker_text with 
 and to insert an HTML element into the dl.Popup but none worked.

When I inspect the element it looks like this:
[image]
Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use dash html elements:

```py
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        marker_element = html.Div(
            [
                html.H1("My Title"),
                html.P("my text")
            ]
        )
        markers.append(
            dl.Marker(
                title=row['title'],
                position=(row['latitude'], row['longitude']),
                children=[
                    dl.Popup(marker_element),
                ],
            )
        )
    children = dl.MarkerClusterGroup(id="markers", children=markers)
```